# How do you put text inside of a progress bar?

Tags: html, text, progress-bar

I would like to put text in the middle of the following progress bar:

```
<progress align="left" class="turnbox2 turnbar" id="myturn"></progress>
```

I would like the text to display the value of the progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use before in css

```css
#myturn{
  height:30px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:orange;
  position:relative;
}

#myturn::before{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  background:green;
  content:'Custom text or 70%';//add your text
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:70%;
  display:flex;
  color:white;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<progress align="left" class="turnbox2 turnbar" id="myturn"></progress>
```

**Update:**

this is work without css:

```css
progress {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: #666;
}

#myturn span {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
}

#myturn {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

progress {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myturn">
    <span data-value="60" style="width: 60%;">custom text or 60%</span>
    <progress value="60" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: Would I have to use a CSS custom property to set the text?

Comment: No you can use js and also you can add span with custom text, check the update

Comment: Would I just do a span Id?

Comment: you should put span out of progress tag and after that added custom css otherwise if you just add span inside progress with id or class that won't show and styles not apply to them.